# TypeError: _dataProvider_server_rest__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3 react-admin, strapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-admin, strapi

I am trying to perform a simple fetch with strapi rest I am using [ra-strapi-rest](https://github.com/nazirov91/ra-strapi-rest) as a dataprovider I am able to fetch the data with Resource from react-admin but when i want to fetch a single record with custom query or a getList in useEffect i am not able to do so

```
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-strapi-rest';

export const strapiDataProvider = simpleRestProvider(
  'http://localhost:1337'
);

 useEffect(() => {   
    strapiDataProvider
      .getList('customers')
      .then((data: any) => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log('error: ', error);
      });
  }, []);
```

I am getting following error

> TypeError: _dataProvider_server_rest__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.strapiDataProvider.getList is not a function

I have also tried to get a single record

```
 useEffect(() => {
    strapiDataProvider
      .getOne('customers', { id: 61 })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log('error: ', error);
      });
  }, []);
```

I am getting same error for the above as well

> TypeError: _dataProvider_server_rest__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.strapiDataProvider.getOne is not a function

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For some fast solution, the issue and advice, has been made here: [Github Issues](https://github.com/nazirov91/ra-strapi-rest/issues/21), to use `<Query>` component, rather than `ra-strapi-rest`.

Comment: @GiorgiGvimradze Thank you for pointing it out. I am the one who opened that issue.